# Where can I find a map with the location of towns and cities in Southern Sudan?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

For a project I have some name of towns and cities in the Southern part of Sudan, the region South Kordofan. Many of these towns I can't find on Google Maps, but I need to know their location.

Example of towns I can't find are: Kuma, Mendi, Kalkutta, Um Serbeba and Al Nugra.

Hope someone knows a good source?

Comment: Search on Sudan Map on google images..you will get the accurate map .

Answer (score 3):

I would first take a look at [Geospatial Data for Sudan](http://www.unitar.org/unosat/sudan) from the United Nations.  Also, note that they provide contacts to inquire about the most up to date GIS data.  I would also recommend contacting NPOs working in South Sudan, as I'm sure they have internal data they may be willing to share.

Answer (score 0):

There is a website called GeoNames which lists all cities around the world but when I entered [these](http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=Kalkutta&country=SD) city names, I could not find them.

However, using the fuzzy search on the site (under advanced options) `Kalkadda` returned a [result](http://www.geonames.org/maps/google_10.969_30.569.html) for Southern Sudan. Perhaps there are some different ways of spelling these cities?